# Import mailbox names from CSV and export distribution groups to another CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, exchange-server-2010, import-from-csv

I need to import a list of e-mails from a CSV file and for each one of them I have to list the distribution groups they are part of, but I can't get it to work.

My CSV is a list of e-mail addresses one below the other:

```
mail1
mail2
mail3
```

I managed to make the script work by manually inputing the names.
Could you help me at the import\export from CSV part?

This is what I have so far:

Manually:

```psh
$User = read-host -Prompt "User Name"
$user_dn = (get-mailbox $user).distinguishedname
"User " + $User + " is a member of the following groups:"
foreach ($group in get-distributiongroup -resultsize unlimited) {
  if ((get-distributiongroupmember $group.identity | select -expand distinguishedname) -contains $user_dn) {$group.name}
}
```

From import:

```psh
$list = import-csv 1.csv
foreach ($entry in $list) {
$user = $entry
$user_dn = (get-mailbox $user).distinguishedname
"User " + $User + " is a member of the following groups:"
foreach ($group in get-distributiongroup -resultsize unlimited) {
  if ((get-distributiongroupmember $group.identity | select -expand distinguishedname) -contains $user_dn) {$group.name}
}
```

I can't make the export work I get the "empty pipe" error.

Comment: Please show the code that is not working, as well as the full error message.

Comment: I think for a project like this, you need to think through how someone is going to consume the results of your output.  For instance, how do you want this CSV to look?

Are you expecting to have these column headings?

`Username,GroupName,GroupName,GroupName,GroupName`

it's hard to envision how that would be useful for the end party recieving the report.  An XML list woudl probably be better, that way the end user can expand and collapse a user to see their groups.

My point: make sure you think it through.  A CSV is probably not a good output format.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I think this will satisfy your needs.

```
get-distributiongroup | ForEach-Object {

$groupName = $_
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupname.Name | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomObject]@{GroupName=$groupname;groupMember=$_.Name}
    }

} | Group-Object -Property GroupMember | Select Name, @{Name=‘Groups‘;Expression={$_.Group.GroupName}}
```

We're getting a big list of all of the distirbution groups, then, for each,resolving the full membership of each group.  For every user we discover who is a member of this group, we create a custom object of "username,groupname".  Once this finishes, we send this to the Group-Object command to let it pick out every unique user, and gather all of their memberships.  We then can send this on to a CSV file, to get an output like this.

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo
"Name","Groups"
"Stephen","Group_1 Group_2 OtherFolks"
"Lenna.Paprocki","Group_2 OtherFolks"
"James.Butt","Group_2 OtherFolks"
"Josephine.Darakjy","OtherFolks"
```

I still think that an XML file is a better way to view this, because you can layer an XSLT file on top to make it very easy for your users to look at the report, click a username and see all of their groups, then collapse as needed.